# How to read the folders inside a folder and get the index.html from each folder and pass as a link in a list (li) tag

Tags: javascript, node.js

As my self-learning with nodejs is still on, I'm of course struggling with some tasks and I'm coming to SO again crying for help.
I intend to create a task that reads the folders inside a specific folder where each folder has an index.html file. 
So, when finding the index.html file, it will pass the path to that file to a

tag as a link.
Example: mainFolder - subfolder - index.html

```
<ul><li><a href="to the folder where the index.html is located">./mainFolder/subfolder/index.html</a></li></ul>
```

Basically, I started scratching the surface of this task and now I'm stuck.

```
/////////////create list of links

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

//joining path of directory 

const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, './dist/mainFolder');

//passing directoryPath and callback function

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {

//handling error
if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
} 
//listing all files using forEach
files.forEach(function (file) {

  var listLinks = [file]
  var mainInd = './dist/mainFolder';
  mainInd.ul = document.createElement('ul');
  var l;

  mainInd.document.getElementById('previewList').appendChild(ul);
  listLinks.forEach(renderLinkList);

  function renderLinkList(element) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  //var a = document.createElement('a');
  //a.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.mypage.com');
  //li.setAttribute('class','item');

  ul.appendChild(li);
  //li.appendChild(a);

  l = (document.createTextNode(element));


  li.innerHTML=li.innerHTML;}console.log(file); });});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Fernando

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code that -

- reads all the files & folders inside the main folder
- iterates through the files & folders
- skips all files
- and finally constructs file path to index.html file inside all sub folders

This snippet prints absolute file path for the index.html file.

You can make it relative file paths as well if needed.

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const index_files = [];
const parent_directory_path = "";

const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, parent_directory_path);

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (error, files) {

    if (!error) {
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            const currDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, file);
            if (fs.existsSync(currDirectoryPath) && fs.lstatSync(currDirectoryPath).isDirectory()) {
                index_files.push(currDirectoryPath + "/index.html");
            }
        });

        console.log(index_files);

    }

});
```

**Update**

As `fs.readdir` API provides all the files and folders inside main folder, we need a condition to skip files.

`fs.existsSync(currDirectoryPath) && fs.lstatSync(currDirectoryPath).isDirectory()` checks if the current file/folder exists and is a folder.

Also this snippet assumes parent directory is current directory. If you want to provide different parent directory path, set the parent directory path value in `parent_directory_path` variable.

Comment: Hi planet_hunter, thank you for your input and great code. After running the script the result is giving me an empty array and I have a few folders inside the main folder. Si there anything we could work out to retrieve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My code assumes that the script is inside main folder. Is the directory of the script and the main folder same?  If so just set the value of `parent_directory_path` variable to the name of main folder. Let me know if it's still not working.